# formatting blocks using inline-block

Tags: html, css

Im trying to format 2 blocks with varied length using inline-block but block-1 gets aligned with the length of block-2. I need to retain the length of block-1 to height of 100px

jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/CGHZ5/5/
```

html:

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id="id1-test">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="id2"></div>
```

css

```
#id1-test{
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    height:15px;
    width:10px;
}

#id1{
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;

    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
#id2{
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;

    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}
```

Comment: not sure I'm understanding what you're asking. What are you retaining, width or height?

Comment: What is "the length of block" exactly? its width?

Answer (score 0):

Use floats instead  of display:inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to the following:

```
    #id1-test{
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    height:15px;
    width:10px;
}

#id1{
    background-color:blue;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
#id2{
    background-color:green;
    display:block;

    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    float: left;
}
```

This does exactly what you want in your fiddle.